# Will government workers furloughed during the shutdown be paid later?

Tags: united-states, government, government-shutdown

When the government of the United States of America reopens, will furloughed government workers be paid for the missed time?

Comment: It's debatable: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/01/government-shutdown-back-pay_n_4025437.html

Comment: I was debating if this was too hypothetical, but the [historic nature of the last 16 shutdowns](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/federal_government/house-and-senate-bills-would-pay-federal-workers-for-shutdown-furloughs/2013/10/03/d2fc8096-2c58-11e3-97a3-ff2758228523_story.html), federal employees were paid for not working, but they don't seem to have the votes yet (tea-party candidates might prevent them.)

Comment: @user1873 i doubt any candidate is going to offer serious opposition to paying them, even tea party candidates, especially any who have a district where furloughed workers live.

Comment: @Ryathai, we will see. **What serious argument is there** for being paid for [furloughed days when they did no work?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/09/23/government-shutdown-furlough-unions_n_3977224.html)? "Transportation Security Administration officers, would be exempted from furloughs and keep working even if the government goes into shutdown mode. In that case, they would get paid retroactively for their service [...] For other workers, the shutdown would lead to an unknown number of furlough days. Congress could later choose to pay workers for the furlough period -- or not."

Comment: http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/10/04/white-house-congress-find-elusive-common-ground-on-paying-federal-workers/

Comment: @user1873 the reason to pay them are all the serious reasons our elected officials care about, namely covering their own ass from their own failures.

Comment: @Ryathal, all the more reason for tea-party candidates to not support those proposals, since they were elected to keep government spending in check. Paying for people to not work seems like fiscal irresponsibility to me. I wonder if voters would see it the same way.

Comment: @Ryathal: The reason for paying them is keeping them. Otherwise they could simply seek other _paid_ jobs.

Comment: @user1873 I'm pretty sure you would feel differently about it if you were one of the people not being paid.

Comment: @DJClayworth, completely. I wish I had a sweet deal with my employer, where they would pay me for not working.

Comment: Let's understand what's happening. These people have had their income stopped because a bunch of politicians decided that's what would happen. They can't pay their bills. If the shutdown continues they might be evicted, or have mortgages foreclosed, can't buy any stuff to use in all that enforced leisure time. Can't go to restaurants or do normal things. The best they can hope for is that if they don't get evicted or foreclosed they will eventually get some money and be able to pay off al their back bills. And you think that's a sweet deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**By default, no.**  The definition of a furlough is that your worker is not working and not being paid for it.  If they were being paid, it would be a vacation instead.  This is why the one-day-a-week furloughing of some workers is a cost-saving measure - it's just gone up to a one-day-a-day furlough.

That being said, there is historical precedent for Congress to retroactively pay for the missed day.  From @user1873's [article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/federal_government/house-and-senate-bills-would-pay-federal-workers-for-shutdown-furloughs/2013/10/03/d2fc8096-2c58-11e3-97a3-ff2758228523_story.html):

> Congress has granted back-pay to furloughed federal workers after each of the past 16 shutdowns that have taken place since 1976.

This is something that has to be done on a case-by-case basis, though.  There's a wide range of possible results, since a bill has to be passed to specifically address this shutdown's back pay.  It could range from doing nothing (which would result in no back pay), to full back pay (as with the others), or some compromise might be worked out (such as 50% back pay, or the option to have retroactively used vacation days to receive full pay).

Comment: If the workers aren't paid - when can they legally quit, i.e. when are their contracts automatically ended?

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Very good question.  As is the question of what happens if back pay is granted but they'd already quit (if they can).  You should ask it as a separate question, though, with a link back to this one.

Comment: [The bill has now been passed for the workers to be paid](http://www.torontosun.com/2013/10/05/us-passes-bill-to-retroactively-pay-furloughed-government-workers).

Comment: @DJClayworth - According to what I'm finding, it's just the House which has passed it (with Obama supporting it).  It's an open question as to whether the Senate will take it up.  It's *likely*, but I don't have much faith in the whole mess right now.  Once Obama gets to sign it, I'll edit the answer to reference it.

Comment: Technically the Senate still has to pass it. But if the Republican-controlled House passed it (unanimously I believe) then the chances of the Democrat-controlled Senate not passing it are virtually none.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Not necessarily.  They may see it as yet another partial funding bill (such as the one to reopen parks), which they've been rejecting so as to not just fund the popular programs.  See Reid's comments [quoted here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/house-votes-to-approve-back-pay-for-furloughed-workers/2013/10/05/936c5b4c-2ddc-11e3-8ade-a1f23cda135e_story.html)

Answer (score -1):

**They likely will be paid retroactively whether they worked or not.**

The House has passed [H.R.3235](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-113hr3235ih/pdf/BILLS-113hr3235ih.pdf) To provide for the compensation of any Federal, State, or local employee furloughed due to a lapse in appropriations which began on or about October 1, 2013.

> (a) IN GENERAL.—Any Federal employee or State or local employee furloughed due to a lapse in appropriations (from the Treasury of the United States) which began on or about October 1, 2013, shall be compensated at such employee’s standard rate of compensation, for the period of such lapse in appropriations, as soon as practicable after such lapse in appropriations ends.

During the mean time, furloughed employees are likely [eligible for unemployment benefits](http://www.dol.gov/sequestration/ucfe.pdf). If the Senate passes and President signs the House bill, those federal employees will be paid for the time they didn't work. This was the previous case in [the last 16 shutdowns](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/federal_government/house-and-senate-bills-would-pay-federal-workers-for-shutdown-furloughs/2013/10/03/d2fc8096-2c58-11e3-97a3-ff2758228523_story.html). They are then supposed to repay any unemployment benefits they received. Considering the governments past record of improper payments, about 12% of federal employees will not only receive a 2+ week vacation, but an additional source of income.

> Program: Unemployment Insurance, Agency:Department of Labor, Reported Improper Payments: $13.7 billion / 12%, Reported Primary Cause(s):Overpayment to claimants who continue to claim benefits after
>   they return to work, ineligibility, and claimants who failed to meet active work search requirements

Comment: Being paid not to work is unusual but perhaps this habit of unscheduled paid vacation was established to avoid haemorrhaging staff in an unpredictable fashion. They'll lose some anyway as some people opt for a reliable cash flow elsewhere.

Comment: It was not a vacation for the people I knew, they had house payments and kids in childcare and no indication if they still had a job. It was extremely stressful for them, and not all government employees are well paid, some government facilities have cafeterias, and the people who work them make about what they would working fast food.